# XSLT replace() function does not seem to be working

Tags: xslt, saxon, xslt-3.0

I am using XSLT to transform a xml schema to JSON format, where there is a pattern facet, as below:

```
                <simpleType>
                <restriction base="string">
                    <pattern value="[A-Z0-9a-z_]+(@\{UUID\}|@\{TIMEMILLIS\})?[A-Z0-9a-z]*"/>
                </restriction>
            </simpleType>
```

While the '\' characters are required for regex escaping, when converting to JSON they need to be further escaped.

I am using XSLT 3.0 with Saxon, as follows:

```
<if test="child::xsi:simpleType/child::xsi:restriction/child::xsi:pattern">
    <text>,"pattern":"</text><value-of select="replace(attribute::value,'\\','\\')"/><text>"</text>
</if>
```

The output still comes out to be

```
"pattern": "[A-Z0-9a-z_]+(@\{UUID\}|@\{TIMEMILLIS\})?[A-Z0-9a-z]*"
```

in the JSON. I have tried many combinations the replace() function doe not seem to work here.

I am probably missing something. I am referring function definition from [here](http://www.xsltfunctions.com/xsl/fn_replace.html).

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: If you want to create JSON with XSLT 3 then I think you should use the `output method="json"` respectively JSON serialization, that would take care of any escaping to be done inside of JSON string values, if that is the problem you are trying to solve. So don't try to create JSON by hand, just create either the XML that `xml-to-json` can consume or create XPath 3.1 maps and serialize them as JSON.

Comment: @MartinHonnen, is there no way to make the replace function work in this case?

Comment: I am sure the `replace` function works as specified https://www.w3.org/TR/xpath-functions/#func-replace, if you want to replace a single `\` with two use `\\\\` in the third argument. I don't see why you would want to construct JSON manually and do a replace here and there where you think you need it instead of relying on existing JSON serialization built into XSLT/XPath 3.

Comment: Also, another reason why the `replace` function is not working is because you are not positioned on the `xsl:pattern` element when you do it. You should do `replace(xsi:simpleType/xsi:restriction/xsi:pattern/@value,'\\','\\\\')"`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To replace `\` with `\\`, you need to write

```
replace($x, '\\', '\\\\')
```

That's because of the rules for escaping in the replacement string. (The rules were poorly chosen, we were trying to be compatible with other languages, but other languages turn out to be completely inconsistent in this area.)

There's another option: use the 'q' flag:

```
replace($x, '\', '\\', 'q')
```

Comment: One point of note, the "replace($x, '\', '\\', 'q')" approach did not work, it did not replace the string. The "replace($x, '\\', '\\\\')" worked, thanks

Answer (score 1):

Use the support in XSLT and XPath 3 for JSON creation and serialization e.g. creating maps and serializing as JSON

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    exclude-result-prefixes="#all"
    version="3.0">

  <xsl:mode on-no-match="shallow-skip"/>

  <xsl:output method="json" indent="yes"/>

  <xsl:template match="pattern">
      <xsl:sequence select="map { local-name() : data(@value) }"/>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/pPzifoX

or creating the XML format that the `xml-to-json` function expects:

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2005/xpath-functions"
    exclude-result-prefixes="#all"
    expand-text="yes"
    version="3.0">

  <xsl:mode on-no-match="shallow-skip"/>
  <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

  <xsl:output method="text" indent="yes"/>

  <xsl:variable name="json-xml">
      <xsl:apply-templates/>
  </xsl:variable>

  <xsl:template match="/">
      <xsl:value-of select="xml-to-json($json-xml, map { 'indent' : true() })"/>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="pattern">
      <map>
          <string key="{local-name()}">{@value}</string>
      </map>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/pPzifoX/1

Comment: I agree that the above would be the correct solution approach. Thanks